# how to submit form data with multiple buttons

Tags: laravel-9

I want to send data to database table. but there are two submit buttons. 1.Accept 2.Reject. When you click the Accept button, the database will receive the input "value = accepted," and when you click the Reject button, the database will receive the input "value = rejected." The problem is that if you click on any button, "input value = accepted" is sent to the table.

```
This is my form.

            @foreach($attendance as $request)
            <form class="d-sm-inline-block" method="POST" action="/update" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">{{$request['id']}}</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$request['id']}}" name="id" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </th>

                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">{{$request['name']}}</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$request['name']}}" name="name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">{{$request['class']}}</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$request['class']}}" name="class" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">{{$request['roll_number']}}</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$request['roll_number']}}" name="rollnumber" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">{{$request['subject_name']}}</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$request['subject_name']}}" name="subject" class="form-control" >
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">{{$request['attendance']}}</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$request['attendance']}}" name="attendance" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">{{$request['status']}}</label>
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{$request['status']}}" name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <input type="hidden" value="Accepted" name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                            <input type="hidden" value="Rejected" name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" action="action" value="accept">accept</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" action="action" value="reject">Reject</button>

                </tr>
            </form>
            @endforeach
```

Comment: an you add your controller?

Comment: function update(Request $req)
    {
        if($req->status =="Accepted")
        {
        $data = attendance::find($req->id);
        $data->status = " Accepted";
        $data->save();
        return redirect('/admindash');
        
        }
        else 
        {
        $data = attendance::find($req->id);
        $data->status = "Rejected";
        $data->save();
        return redirect('/admindash');
        }}

Comment: I removed other table values to make the code shorter in comment. actual code has some other values too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove:

```
 <div class="mb-3">
        <input type="hidden" value="Accepted" name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
          <input type="hidden" value="Rejected" name="status" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
      </div>
```

and change this:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" action="action" value="accept">accept</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" action="action" value="reject">Reject</button>
```

to:

```
 <button type="submit" name="status" class="btn btn-success" action="action" value="accept">accept</button>
 <button type="submit" name="status" class="btn btn-warning" action="action" value="reject">Reject</button>
```

Your submit buttons have no **name** attribute so their values won't be there in the request.

Comment: Ok thanks bro. let me try it.

Comment: Yep, it's working. Thanks for your time. I was stuck there for the  2 to 3 days.